# Remove duplicates from multi-dimensional array. Numbers and number strings are equal

Tags: types, duplicates, comparison-operators

I have it almost down, but cant figure out how to compare the number and number strings.

```
flattenAndUnique([["hello", "abc"], [true], ["abc"], [123, "123"]])
// should return
// ["hello", "abc", true, 123]
```

I have it flattened, and i have number to number/string to string comparisons down.

```
var flat = arr.reduce(function(arrA, arrB) {
    return arrA.concat(arrB);
});
var unique = flat.filter(function(el, pos) {
    return flat.indexOf(el) === pos;
});
```

Comment: `123` is not the same as `'123'` tho. would you treat `true` the same as `'true'`? how about `'True'` the same as `'TRUE'`? is `[]` equal to `''`?

Comment: I am treating them the same in this question. So 123 and '123' would be equal. True and 'true' are not. 'True' and 'TRUE' would be. [] and '' would not be. I was looking for an approach as well. I just couldn't get my head around the logic.

Comment: it was a brain-teaser someone gave me, and I was stumped.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [["hello", "abc"], [true], ["abc"], [123, "123"]]

// you're trying to do a horrible thing
// so you get a horrible function like this
const unsafeParseInt = x => {
  let int = Number.parseInt(x, 10);
  return Number.isNaN(int) ? x : int;
}

const concat = (x,y) => x.concat(y);
const flatten = xs => xs.reduce(concat, []);
const uniques = xs => xs.filter((x,pos) => xs.indexOf(x) === pos);

let output = uniques(flatten(input).map(unsafeParseInt));

console.log(output);
```